# the start button on my stopwatch resets the timer after stop has been activated swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer

Why does the start button on my stopwatch resets the timer after stop has been pressed? Everything works fine until I stop the timer and then restart it. It should continue from the point where it was stopped but instead it resets the timer to 0. Here is my code:

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var timer = NSTimer()
var startTime = NSTimeInterval()

@IBOutlet var displayTimeLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {

    if !timer.valid {

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

}

@IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()
}

func updateTime() {

    let currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

    let hours = UInt8(elapsedTime / 3600)
    elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(hours) * 3600)

    let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60)
    elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

    let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
    elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)

    let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 100)

    let strHours = String(format: "%02d", hours)
    let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
    let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
    let strFraction = String(format: "%02d", fraction)

    displayTimeLabel.text = "\(strHours):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds):\(strFraction)"

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: You reset `startTime` in your `start` method. If you want to be able to continue on, don't do this

Comment: If I take that line of code out, then I get this issue: fatal error: floating point value cannot be converted to UInt8 because it is greater than UInt8.max @Paulw11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting your `startTime` each time the `start` method is called. You only want to do this the first time it is called.  You can use optionals to determine the state correctly and only set the `startTime` when it is initially nil.

You could then create a reset button with a function that simply sets `startDate = nil`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer : NSTimer?
    var startTime? : NSTimeInterval?
    var accumulatedTime = NSTimeInterval()

    @IBOutlet var displayTimeLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {

        guard self.timer == nil else {
            return
        }

        self.startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {

        guard self.timer != nil else {
            return
        }

        self.timer!.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil
    }

    func updateTime() {

        let currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        let intervalTime = currentTime - startTime!
        self.startTime = currentTime
        self.accumulatedTime += intervalTime

        var elapsedTime = self.accumulatedTime

        let hours = UInt8(elapsedTime / 3600)
        elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(hours) * 3600)

        let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60)
        elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

        let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
        elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)

        let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 100)

        let timeString = String(format:"%02d:%02d:%02d.%02d",hours,minutes,seconds,fraction)
        displayTimeLabel.text = timeString

    }
}
```

Comment: This works a little better. But why does the timer not continue from the point where the stop button was pressed? It seems as if it's still running in the background and updates the label once start is tapped again. How do I now make it continue from the exact point when the stop button was pressed?

Comment: Because your approach is to take the difference between the start time and the stop time, rather than to accumulate time while the timer is running.

Comment: See my updated answer; it resets startTime each time the timer fires (and each time you press the start button).  This way it can calculate the elapsed time between timer firings and the total elapsed time, stopping when the timer stops